# How to make Stored Queries for WFS 2.0.0 in Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, wfs, query

I am a new user of Geoserver. I have created a WFS and also could connect it with the QGIS WFS  2.0.0 Client plugin available now. But as like the default WFS link in that plugin I am not able to make a query in my service. Also the metadata is not coming for my service. Can anyone help me in this regards?

What do I actually have to do to make the stored queries and also to get metadata?
Where to start doing that?

Answer (score 2):

**StoredQuery** (Using a CreateStoredQuery POST Request)
How to add and use Stored Queries (in German language)
http://www.weichand.de/2012/04/22/wfs-2-0-stored-queries-beispiele/

**Metadata** 
How to add the MetadataURL for each FeatureType (in German language)
http://www.weichand.de/2012/08/26/metadatenviewer-fur-qgis-plugins-inspire-atom-client-wfs-2-0-client/

But please have look at:
http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/GeoServer-2-2-INSPIRE-Download-Service-compatibility-td5008259.html

Comment: Hi Juergen, Thanks for your answer. I could make the stored query. but I am having the following error: java.lang.NullPointerException null -- in the WFS 2.0 QGIS plugin. can you tell me why I am having this type of error?

Comment: I used Firefox Poster to make stored query. and also tried with your bbox query example.

Comment: Probably this bug: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GEOS-5254

Comment: Yes Juergen, I have the same problem you told. But how can I overcome from this problem? Can you help me? I put the type name in the request url and I got the whole list of my feature. but the problem is I am always having the whole list of my feature. if I decrease my bounding box it also gives me whole features. and also still having same error: java.lang.NullPointerException null in WFS plugin QGIS